# In publications section of application, I'm asked what database the journal is indexed in. Where can I find that information?

Tags: publications, journals, application, indexing

I am applying to a university for a PhD and in the application it asks for information on journal publications. And under that it asks for journal's Impact factor and database the journal is indexed in.

What is meant by **database the journal is indexed in**? How can I find it?

I have my journal submitted to **BMC systems biology** and I found the 2015 impact factor to be 2.213. What is the database the journal is indexed in?

Comment: Wow, that's a weird thing for them to ask. Is there space for exactly one entry? What about journals that are indexed by more than one database?

Comment: @ff524 It's a PDF form, so I can write more than one entry,I guess.

Comment: Well, then, here you go: [About BMC systems biology](https://bmcsystbiol.biomedcentral.com/about). Scroll down to "Indexing Services". There are about 20 on the list :)

Comment: @ff524  Thank you. But I can't include all that in the application. As it says "You can also access all articles published by BioMed Central on SpringerLink." Can I use SpringerLink as the database the journal is indexed in?

Comment: I would answer "Google". (And then I would not get the job.)

Comment: Just write SCI-E, SCOPUS. that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a poorly worded question.

However, if I were to guess their intentions, they might be interested in whether the journal appears in the "Science Citation Index - Expanded" or "Social Sciences Citation Index". Or another influential one is whether it is in the Proquest index.

The reason I say this, is that inclusion in these indices are sometimes used as a minimal criteria for legitimacy as a journal for inclusion in world rankings.

E.g., The Shanghai rankings use:

> ARWU uses six objective indicators to rank world universities,
>   including the number of alumni and staff winning Nobel Prizes and
>   Fields Medals, number of highly cited researchers selected by Thomson
>   Reuters, number of articles published in journals of Nature and
>   Science, **number of articles indexed in Science Citation Index -
>   Expanded and Social Sciences Citation Index**, and per capita
>   performance of a university. More than 1200 universities are actually
>   ranked by ARWU every year and the best 500 are published.

You can search for inclusion in Science and Social Science Citation Index [here](http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/mjl/).

Comment: BMC Systems Biology is in SCIENCE CITATION INDEX EXPANDED. So would SCIENCE CITATION INDEX EXPANDED work as the database the journal is indexed in